# Highlight Highcharts Organization Chart nodes

Tags: highcharts, highlight, organization

I'm using Highcharts to create organization charts that where each node can be collapsed when clicked as in provided example : http://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/83uktasc/

I would like to highlight the full path (from top level parent until the child node) when the mouse hover a node.

There is an example here : https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-use-an-org-chart-more-effectively/

I saw that the highlighting is provided in

```
@import 'https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css';
```

but it only highlights the first level parent.

How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the colors more bright in a similar way as the collapsing is implemented. Example:

```
const operateChildren = (point, operation) => {
    point.linksFrom.forEach(link => {
        operation([
            link.toNode.graphic,
            link.graphic,
            link.toNode.dataLabel
        ]);

        operateChildren(link.toNode, operation);
    });
};

const hideElements = (elements) => {
    elements.forEach(element => {
        element.hide();
    });
}

const showElements = (elements) => {
    elements.forEach(element => {
        element.show();
    });
}

const highlighElements = (elements) => {
    const color = elements[0].attr('fill');

    elements[0].attr({
        fill: Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(0.3).get()
    });
};

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        if (this.linksFrom && this.linksFrom[0]) {
                            if (this.linksFrom[0].graphic.visibility === "hidden") {
                                operateChildren(this, showElements);
                            } else {
                                operateChildren(this, hideElements);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    mouseOver: function() {
                        if (this.linksFrom) {
                            highlighElements([this.graphic]);
                            operateChildren(this, highlighElements);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            ...
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s70ujvwy/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Color

Comment: So, is it possible by cllicking on a node to hightlight the full path to it?